# Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly executing mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, java-home

I want to execute mvn clean install, but it displays the following error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
   We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
```

When I execute "echo $JAVA_HOME" it displays:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

What can I do?

Comment: Close and reopen your terminal (the one running maven or intellij), to be sure `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly

Comment: Check if that java binary actually works... Check what java binary is on your PATH

Comment: How are you executing Maven? In the same bash than you run the command, or via a tool like Jenkins?

Comment: did u try updating your environment variable?